# Fit text content with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I have and HTML container like

```
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <span>short text width random length comes here</span>
    <a>postedByUserName</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

the container must be responsive, there's a working demo here

```js
var $input = $('.input input'),
$container = $('.container'),
$value = $('.value');
$value.text('Container width: ' + $input.val() + 'px');
$container.width($input.val()); 

$input.on('input', function(){
 $container.width($input.val());  
    $value.text('Container width: ' + $input.val() + 'px');
});
```

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: bisque;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
}
  p {
    background: orange;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
    a {
      color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="input">
  Min. 50px
    <input type="range" min="50" max="600" step="10" name="container_width">
    Max: 600px
    <br/>
    <div class="value"></div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <span>Some random text comes here</span>
      <a>postedByUserName</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you set the width of the container to 100px *(range input can be used)* you will see that the link element with user name is not visible anymore.
How can I make to not put the link on the next line but show the text continuously element and show the user name with ellipsis, this should happen only when the container height is 80 pixel until than the ellipsis should not be applied on the text. The template inside the `div.container` can be changed, but the user name should look like a link and should be a clickable element? 
I need a CSS+HTML solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your `p`.

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

**Explaination**:

1. `overflow: hidden;` : Hides the characters beyond specified width.
2. `white-space: nowrap;` : Say the browser not to break the text into multiple lines.
3. `text-overflow: ellipsis;` : Creates the ellipsis when the text overflow's.

---

**Updated Snippet**:

```js
var $input = $('.input input'),
  $container = $('.container'),
  $value = $('.value');
$value.text('Container width: ' + $input.val() + 'px');
$container.width($input.val());

$input.on('input', function() {
  $container.width($input.val());
  $value.text('Container width: ' + $input.val() + 'px');
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: bisque;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
p {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="input">
    Min. 50px
    <input type="range" min="50" max="600" step="10" name="container_width">Max: 600px
    <br/>
    <div class="value"></div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <span>Some random text comes here</span>
      <a>postedByUserName</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not exactly what I need. The height of the `p` paragragh should increase until its height is 80 pixel that's why I added  `max-height: 80px` and only than should apply the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

I have played your code around. Please try to check it a little bit like this,

```
<div class="container" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 190px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
    <span>Some random text comes here</span>
    <a>postedByUserName</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe I misguided you but the height of the container and it's content should increase until it is 80px and only than should the ellipsis be applied.